# Об'єм і обсяг - чи це повні синоніми?

Tags: вибір-слова, терміни, синоніми

В [Російсько-українському фразеологічному словнику 1927р. (В. Підмогильний, Є. Плужник)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BC&scope=all&dicts=3&highlight=on) надано такі відповідники російського *объем*:

> **Объем** – обсяг, обшир; *(матем.)* – об’єм. В полном объеме – в цілому
>   обсягу.

В СУМ-11 
ОБ'Є́М, у, чол.

> 1. Величина чого-небудь, вимірювана в кубічних одиницях. Об'єм вийнятої земляної маси завжди буде більший, ніж об'єм цієї ж маси в
>      умовах її природного залягання (Інженерна геодезія, 1959, 109); Треба
>      було визначити поверхню і об'єм конуса (Олесь Донченко, V, 1957, 421);
>
>    //  Форма, обриси чого-небудь у трьох вимірах; об'ємність. Об'єм і
>      форма належать до тих зовнішніх якостей предметів, передавання яких у
>      найбільшій мірі залежить від освітлення (Довідник фотолюбителя, 1959,
>      64);
>
>    //  спец. Кількісні виміри чого-небудь. Ударним об'ємом серця
>      називається кількість крові, що її виштовхує серце за одне скорочення
>      (Шкільна гігієна, 1954, 79).
> 2. рідко. Те саме, що обсяг 1. Об'єм нашого збірника не позволив би друкувати великі повісті або романи (Михайло Коцюбинський, III, 1956,
>      238); Збільшення масштабів і темпів розвитку народного господарства
>      супроводжується лавиноподібним ростом об'єму інформації (Знання та
>      праця, 12, 1966, 2).   **В усьому (цілому, цілім) об'ємі** — цілком,
>      повністю, нічого не виключаючи.

Цікавить обмеження щодо вживання слова *об'єм*: у першому джерелі воно наведене з поміткою "математичне", тобто вживане лише як термін. У другому воно вже наводиться з тлумаченням "те ж саме, що *обсяг*". То як вживати це слово - лише в математичному значенні чи як повний синонім слову *обсяг*?

Comment: Чесно кажучи, зовсім не зрозумів запитання. Обидва джерела досить однозначно відповідають на це запитання. Відповідь на заголовок запитання — ні, не повні синоніми, бо *обсяг* не використовується у значенні «математична величина, що вимірюється у кубічних одиницях». Відповідь на запитання «лише в математичному значенні чи як повний синонім слову обсяг?» — СУМ прямо позначає, що *обʼєм* у значенні «Те саме, що обсяг» з міткою **рідко**. «Рідко» — це часто вживаний евфемізм замість слова «увага, суржик, тримайтесь подалі від цього».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

З СУМ-11

> ***[ОБСЯГ](http://sum.in.ua/s/obsjagh)*** **1.** Розмір, величина чого-небудь. **2.** Межі, коло чого-небудь.
>
> ***[ОБ'Є́М](http://sum.in.ua/s/ob.jem)*** **1.** Величина чого-небудь, вимірювана в кубічних одиницях.
>   //  Форма, обриси чого-небудь у трьох вимірах; об'ємність. //  спец.
>   Кількісні виміри чого-небудь. **2.** рідко. Те саме, що обсяг

З сайту [OnlineCorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%8F%D0%B3/)

> ***Об’єм*** — розмір чогось у довжину, висоту й ширину, вимірюваний у кубічних одиницях;
>   ***Обсяг*** — взагалі розмір, величина, кількість, значення, важливість, межі чогось.

[image]

Дані слова не можуть бути повними синонімами, оскільки ***обсяг*** не можемо використовувати у значенні математичного терміна, як ***"об'єм"***. Хоча є значення *"те саме, що обсяг"*, проте поряд примітка *рідко*. Варто розмежовувати вживання цих двох слів.